# Showing cards head up

Tags: poker-strategy

One player goes all in one player  remaining the player turns his hand over before calling to try get a reaction out the player that has gone all in is this allowed

Comment: Mike Caro said that showing his cards at Showdown gets great reactions and has earned him tons of money. Explain that...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the game, customs vary between tournaments, cash games, location and  limits.

Answer (score 0):

No. Players must not reveal their cards during a live hand unless a rule requires it.

A standard response is that any hand deliberately revealed when not permitted is dead. Further penalties can also be imposed.

Comment: Accidentally exposing live hands without permission, a warning and the opponent is not allowed to (re)raise. Nobody was ever daft enough to let it happen twice in a day. Deliberate exposure when not permitted? It never happened because players knew they'd be mucked. Not to mention the social stigma, let alone the chance of other formal penalties.

Answer (score 0):

It is against the rules.  You cannot even announce your card(s) when the hand is live.

What I have seen with inadvertent is they can only call or fold. They cannot bet out or raise.

To award the hand is extreme.  It would be like a 1 orbit penalty.

There are dealers and floor men on this site that will hopefully weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is against the rules ... I saw that at TV , not sure if it was EPT , but I think so , Hand was dead and penalty of 1 orbit .